# how to compare two xml with different attribute values in same tags

Tags: java, xunit

I use XUnit. for me it is two identical XML, but the test is failed. How to compare them using Xunit? or something else?

```
public void testIdentical() throws Exception {
        String myControlXML = "<struct>" +
                "<int a=\"1\"></int>" +
                "<int a=\"2\"></int>" +
                "</struct>";
        String myTestXML = "<struct>" +
                "<int a=\"2\"></int>" +
                "<int a=\"1\"></int>" +
                "</struct>";
        Diff myDiff = new Diff(myControlXML, myTestXML);
        assertTrue("my test" + myDiff, myDiff.similar());
}

java.lang.AssertionError: my test org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff
[different] Expected attribute value '1' but was '2' - comparing <int a="1"...> at /struct[1]/int[1]/@a to <int a="2"...> at /struct[1]/int[1]/@a
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in XmlUnit. From their documentation:

> Two documents are considered to be "similar" if they contain the same
>   elements and attributes regardless of order.

You could try reformatting them to apply a specific, canonical, order yourself before passing them into Diff.